# While-loop issues

Tags: java

I'm reading data from a serial port inside a while-loop as follows:

```
while((len = this.getIn().read(buffer)) > 0) {
    data = new String(buffer, 0, len);
    System.out.println("data len " + len);
    handleModemresponse(data);
}
```

but, while reading the data from the stream starts, the main AWT window, which has a disconnect button, is not getting any listeners (the whole window not getting listeners). It only listens when transfer completes, i.e., outside the while-loop.

I want my AWT window to listen for my actions when it is in the while-loop also.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Create a new Thread for the read action.

```
public class LongProcess implements Runnable {
  public void startProcess() {
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
  }

      public void run() {
// Define inputstream here
        while((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
         data = new String(buffer, 0, len);
         System.out.println("data len " + len);
         handleModemresponse(data);
        }
      }
    }
```

**EDIT** (after comment Tom Hawtin - tackline):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LongProcess ());
```

Comment: java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater to get back into the AWT EDT thread.

Comment: er...invokeLater is for notifiying the gui when the thread is finshed:

finally in run() do something like.
...ies.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
    ...public void run() {
           gui.taskIsDone( result );
....

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have everything in one thread - thus while your working method is in progress, your GUI seems blocked and does not respond to any actions until the loop ends.

You have to separate your GUI attendance in one thread and your working method in another.

Answer (score 2):

The read method you are calling is blocking. You need to move it in a different thread in order for your listeners to keep working.

Comment: To be more accurate, blocking I/O isn't the issue here. It's the long-running process on GUI thread that is creating the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you should be pushing this while loop into a separate thread so as to not tie up your AWT thread during the transfer.

Comment: @Pax: Sorry for the formatting which erased your formatting ;) You did a much better job at rephrasing this question.

Comment: No probs, @VonC, that often happens, mainly because I'm anal retentive about making the question look good once I start editing, and I take too long.